# Mysql group by multiple columns with different values

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have as an example this table

```
id user_id user_name profile_image post_id
1     10       A         a.png         1
2     11       B         x.png         1
3     12       D         j.png         4
4     13       F         g.png         4
```

What I want is to group rows by `post_id`, so that the results will be like the following one:

```
post_id    user_ids      user_names  profile_images
    1      {10,11}        {A,B}      {a.png,x.ping}
```

I tried using `GROUP BY` and `JOIN`s, also `json_object`.
How can I achieve that?

Comment: Your expected output looks off to me.  Shouldn't you be expecting JSON _arrays_?  E.g. `[10, 11]` ?

Comment: If creating a json_object, you would use group by.

Comment: Your expected output is not valid JSON as far as I know.

Comment: i just noticed that

Comment: i want a json array ,smh @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: MySql version : 5.7.21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On MySQL version `5.7.22` or later we can use [`JSON_ARRAYAGG`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg):

```
SELECT
    post_id,
    JSON_ARRAYAGG(user_id) AS user_ids,
    JSON_ARRAYAGG(user_name) AS user_names,
    JSON_ARRAYAGG(profile_image) AS profile_images
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY post_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT`.

```
select 
post_id,
GROUP_CONCAT(user_id) as user_ids,
GROUP_CONCAT(username) as usernames,
GROUP_CONCAT(profile_image) as profile_images 
from <your_table> group by post_id;
```

Then, you can format the output accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

you can use group_concat for grouping values

```
  select post_id
      , concat( '{', group_concat(user_id), '}' ) 
      , concat( '{', group_concat(user_name), '}' ) 
      , concat( '{', group_concat(profile_images), '}' ) 
  from  
  group by post_id
```

and format the result using concat

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working using `JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('field1', value1, 'field2', value2))`. Will lead to `[{ field1: 1, field2: 2 }, { field1: 3, field2: 4 }]`.